# animate scrollRangeToVisible with spring animation

Tags: swift, animation

I am attempting animating a scroll.  In the code below, `detailText` is a `UITextView`. Not sure why the `UIView.animate` function does not work.

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, delay: 0.0,
                               usingSpringWithDamping: 0.6,
                               initialSpringVelocity: 6.0,
                               options: [.curveEaseIn], animations: {

  let rangeOfTag = (self.detailText.text as NSString).range(of: "satisfactorily")

  self.detailText.scrollRangeToVisible(rangeOfTag)                                                                                          

    }, completion: nil)
```

I tried the foregoing in:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews()
```

with no success in creating the spring.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

You may use this snippet to get the vibration.

```
   UIView.animate(withDuration: 3.0, delay: 0.0,
                   usingSpringWithDamping: 0.1,
                   initialSpringVelocity: 0.9,
                   options: [.curveEaseIn, .overrideInheritedCurve], animations: {

                   let rangeOfTag = (self.detailText.text as NSString)
                    .range(of: "satisfactorily")
                    let glyRange =    self.detailText.layoutManager.glyphRange(forCharacterRange: rangeOfTag, actualCharacterRange: nil)
                    let rect =     self.detailText.layoutManager.lineFragmentRect(forGlyphAt: NSMaxRange(glyRange), effectiveRange: nil)
                self.detailText.scrollRectToVisible(rect, animated: false)



    }, completion: nil)
```

Comment: E.Coms - Thank you.  It worked.  Unfortunately, I am unable publicly post the score.

Comment: @KDiaz: Good to hear that the answer solved your problem! Please accept the answer by clicking on the small check next to it which then turns green.

Comment: E.Coms - I would if I could.  However, when I click on the up arrow, I am informed I do not have enough reputation points for the click to be recorded publicly.

Comment: I am fine with that. Maybe you can ask a new question about how to do this and somebody will help you.